# Multiple ids in a unique column each and joining them to get details of each on the same line

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having in one table a master_id, and student_id. I want to write a query that would print out both the names of the master and student on the same line while joining their details from another table.

master student table

```
id - 1
fullname - Derek Jason
type: master
id - 2
fullname - John Mason
type: student
```

assignments table

```
id - 1
from - 1
to - 2
```

So I'm trying to write a query that would return the results from the assignment table like

Results

```
id - 1
master- Derek
student - John Manson
```

I've tried this query but I'd need help to complete it.

```
SELECT name AS master FROM `assignments`
LEFT JOIN master_student ON assignments.from = master_student.id
```

Comment: SQL tables have rows and columns.  It is not clear what the rows and columns are in your data.  Can you better format the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you just want two joins:

```
SELECT a.id, ms.name AS master, mt.name as student
FROM assignments a LEFT JOIN
     master_student ms
     ON a.from = ms.id LEFT JOIN
     master_student mt
     ON a.to = mt.id;
```

Note:  `from` and `to` are really, really bad column names because they are SQL keywords.